# Hibernate - Multiple mapping on a single entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I had Two questions.
1) Can we have this sort of relationship in hibernate - Entities(say Seller, Buyer, Product) and seller having one-to-many to Product and buyer having one-to-many to Product using annotations?

2) Can we update Seller/Buyer entity without passing Product object in above scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes - `@OneToMany private List<Products>` - i would rather say many to many here
2. Yes - You can update any parent entities without its children.